# ending condition in finding magic index in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, binary-search

I have a question in the solution I'm referring for the below question

> A magic index in an array A[l.. .n-l] is defined to be an index such
>   that A[i] = i. Given a sorted array of distinct integers, write a
>   method to find a magic index, if one exists, in array A.

The solution I'm referring looks like. Assume 's' stands for start and 'e' stands for end.

```
int fun(int a[], int s, int e)
{
 if(s > e || s < 0 || e >= array.length)
  return -1;

 mid = (s + e)/2;

 if(mid == a[mid])
  return mid;
 else if(mid < a[mid])
  return fun(a, s, mid-1);
 else 
  return fun(a, mid+1, e); 
}
```

I'm not sure about the ending condition here.

I feel the ending condition should just be

```
if(s > e)
 return -1;
```

Let's consider the two extreme cases when the magic index is not present

```
CASE 1 - going left till index 0
Say the array looks as follows a[] = {2,10,20,30,40,50}

mid = (0+6)/2 = 3 , call fun(0,2)
mid = (0+2)/2 = 1 , call fun(0,0)
mid = (0+0)/2 = 0 , call fun(0,-1)
since start > end, -1 is returned

CASE 2 - going right till the last element
Say the array looks as follows a[] = {-20,-10,-5,-4,-3,30,80}

mid = (0+6)/2 = 3 , call fun(4,6)
mid = (4+6)/2 = 5 , call fun(6,6)
mid = (6+6)/2 = 6 , call fun(7,6)
since start > end, -1 is returned
```

Moreover, I feel the extra conditions given in the solution can never be reached.

- I feel s<0 cannot be reached because we are never subtracting anything from 's'. I feel the smallest value that 's' can take is 0. Maybe 'e' can be < 0, but not 's'
- Also I feel e >= array.length is not possible since we are never adding anything to 'e'. Maybe 's' can be greater than or equal to array.length but not 'e'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre right s>e is enough. S can never be below zero since it's either preserved or equal to (s+e)/2+1>=s+1 (since e>=s), so it's always larger or equal to the initial value passed, which is zero. Similarly it can be shown that e<=n-1 always, so the extra conditions are redundant.